# MSIEXEC batch file works in W7 but not W8

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer, msitransform

I am having major issues getting a batch file to run correctly on Windows 8.

The below runs fine in Windows 7, however doesn't run in Windows 8. If I remove the `/quiet` flag I get the installer come up, but it asks me all the installation questions that the transform file is supposed to be answering.

```
@ECHO off
msiexec /i "\\syd-san01\software$\fortinet\forticlient.msi" TRANSFORMS="\\syd-san01\software$\fortinet\forticlient.mst" /quiet /norestart
pause
@exit
```

I have tried changing the `TRANSFORMS=` to `TRANSFORM=` and `/t` (no `=`) however this has made no difference.

Does anyone know of any changes to msiexec in Windows 8 that would stop this file from running correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I would take a verbose log to check, but the first thing I'd look at is that the install may require elevation on Windows 8, and so it's failing silently. It can't ask for an elevation prompt in silent mode.

Comment: I'm running it as domain admin with UAC disabled. I'll see about the verbpose logs and see what I can figure out. Cheers @PhilDW

Comment: The verbose log should also point any launch conditions, if present, that may stop the installation. First, you can try to remove the quiet switch to see what error message you get.